# How to fix lag on simple plotly 3d graph?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, lag

I am making a simple 3d graph with 3 planes in plot.ly but when I load the graph it takes 30 seconds to even load and when I attempt to rotate it at all it lags horribly and eventually just crashes.

I have already tried offline, connected to a hotspot, different wifis, and a VPN but none of it really changes anything. I'm mostly just confused that I would have so much lag because the code is relatively rudimentary.

```
import numpy as np
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go



def the_plane(x,y,z, showscale=False):  
    return go.Surface(x=x, 
                      y=y,
                      z=z,
                      showscale=showscale,
                      colorbar=dict(thickness=20, ticklen=4))


volume = lambda x,y,z: x*np.exp(-x**2-y**2-z**2)
x = np.linspace(-3,3, 50)
y = np.linspace(-3,3, 50)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.zeros(x.shape)
surfcolor_z = volume(x,y,z)
slice_z = the_plane(x,y,z)


x = np.linspace(-3,3, 50)
z = np.linspace(-3,3, 50)
x, z = np.meshgrid(x,y)
y = 0 * np.ones(x.shape)
surfcolor_y = volume(x,y,z)


slice_y = the_plane(x,y,z)

y = np.linspace(-3,3, 50)
z = np.linspace(-3,3, 50)
y, z = np.meshgrid(x,y)
x = 0 * np.ones(x.shape)


slice_x = the_plane(x,y,z)


axis = dict(showbackground=True, 
            backgroundcolor="rgb(230, 230,230)",
            gridcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)",      
            zerolinecolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)"  
            )


layout = go.Layout(
         title='3D plot', 
         width=700,
         height=700,
         scene=dict(xaxis=axis,
                    yaxis=axis, 
                    zaxis=dict(axis, range=[-2,2]),
                    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=1)
                    )
        )
fig = go.Figure(data=[slice_z, slice_y, slice_x], layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Is this in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @iampotential no it is not a jupyter notebook